# how to align a text beside form at CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a problem: I want to align an interactive text which is already in the left of a slider. So, I just want to align a login form in the right of that interactive text.

I have inform all the codes as well as an image of the output right now and the image inside the slider:

The image inside the slider:

[image]

The output of the code right now:

[image]

Desired outcome:

[image]

**This is the CSS + HTML code of the text :**

```
<div class="container-wrap">
        <aside id="fh5co-hero">
            <div class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                <li style="background-image: url(images/graduation1.png);">
                    <div class="overlay-gradient"></div>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-md-pull-3 slider-text">
                        


                                
                                      <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="typing-demo">
     Hello!
     <br> Welcome to the website- </br>
    </div>
</div> 

<style>
    .wrapper {
  height: 50vh;
  /*This part is important for centering*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.typing-demo {
  width: 22ch;
  animation: typing 2s steps(22), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 2px solid;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  color:    #FFFFFF
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
}
    
@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent
  }
}
    </style>


**this is the CSS + HTML code of the form :**

    

<html>

<div class="container"></div>
<div class="form">
  <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/169963/hat.svg"/></div>
  <form class="register-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
    <button>create</button>
    <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
  </form>
  <form class="login-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <button>login</button>
    <p class="message">Are you a Business/Society? <a href="#">Register here</a></p>
  </form>
</div>




      
</html>

<style>

.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: right;
  padding: 60px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
.form .thumbnail {
  background: #ffd700;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form .thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.form input {
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  outline: 0;
  background: #ffd700;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #ffd700;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #ffd700;
}

/* END Form */
    </style>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please? What do you want to align where? Also if you have an image of the desired outcome please share it with us.

Comment: in general i want the login form to be in the right of the slider . i have upload an image of the place that i want it to be named " desired outcome"

Comment: `i have inform all …` has been begging clarification: Please check if the edit improves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to your problem. The main thing you where missing is **display: inline-block;**  This allows DIVs to be next to each other.

```
.flexslider {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }
.row {
        float: left;
    }
.container {
        float: right;
    }
```

Comment: also the problem not solved it change the header and make it in the right..